# AD FS 2.0 certificate issue

Tags: adfs

I have an window 2008 R2 server, and installed AD and ADFS 2.0.
After configure ADFS, then integration with other System.
I have encountered an issue when i integration. Following error message was found from windows event log.

> An error occurred during an attempt to build the certificate chain for the relying party trust 'http://carlos-carlosad-ca.com/adfs/services/trust' certificate identified by thumbprint 'BD188AC26E0BDDC167D1A224493AB206515243F4'. Possible causes are that the certificate has been revoked, the certificate chain could not be verified as specified by the relying party trust's encryption certificate revocation settings or certificate is not within its validity period. 
>   You can use Windows PowerShell commands for AD FS 2.0 to configure the revocation settings for the relying party encryption certificate. 
>   Relying party trust's encryption certificate revocation settings: None 
>   The following errors occurred while building the certificate chain:
>   MSIS2013: A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock.
>   User Action: 
>   Ensure that the relying party trust's encryption certificate is valid and has not been revoked. 
>   Ensure that AD FS 2.0 can access the certificate revocation list if the revocation setting does not specify "none" or a "cache only" setting. 
>   Verify your proxy server setting. For more information about how to verify your proxy server setting, see the AD FS 2.0 Troubleshooting Guide (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=182180).

I have export "Token-Signing", and import it to my integration system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a programming question. And the text clearly states that the signing certificate is expired. Have them "the others" put a valid cert in there. That is what ADFS requires.